# Preselect /default value in meteor autocomplete

Tags: javascript, meteor, autocomplete

I am using https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/meteor-autocomplete

I would like to know how I can preselect/prepopulate a value in autocomplete input text. If that is not possible is there any way to set a default value? HTML value="default" does not work.

I am trying to use it in an email composer's to, cc, bcc fields. By default the input fields have some default user selected, ( it may be different depending on case) but they can change it using the search in autocomplete.

Comment: Could you maybe provide your current code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code ( sorry there was no option to edit, hence replying from my other account)

```
settings() {
return {
  position: 'bottom',
  limit: 80,
  rules: [
    { // token: '',
      collection: Subscribers,
      sort: true,
      field: 'status',
      matchAll: true,
      filter: { status: { $ne: 'deleted' } },
      template: Template.standardSubscribers,
      selector(match) {
        let regex;
        regex = _.map(match.split(' '), function(key) { return new RegExp('^' + key, 'i'); });
        return {
          '$or': [
            { 'firstName': { '$in': regex } },
            { 'lastName': { '$in': regex } },
            { 'email': { '$in': regex } },
            { 'address': { '$in': regex } },
            { 'secondaryEmail': { '$in': regex } }, 
            { 'businessName': { '$in': regex } }
          ]};
      },
    }
  ]
};
```

},

```
<template name="standardSubscribers">
<span class="">{{businessName}} {{#if isBusinessName businessName}} -- {{/if}} {{firstName}} {{lastName}} -- {{email}} -- {{secondaryEmail}} -- {{status}} -- {{address}}</span>
```

```
'autocompleteselect #email-to' (event, template, doc) {
if (doc.businessName) {
  event.target.value = doc.businessName + '<' + doc.email + '> --- ' + doc.status;
} else {
  event.target.value = doc.firstName + ' ' + doc.lastName + '<' + doc.email + '> --- ' + doc.status;
}
```

},

```
{{> inputAutocomplete settings=settings style="width: 73%" value="yogesh" id="email-cc" class="form-control" name="emailCC"  autocomplete="off"  }}
```